# Declaring a function within setInterval does not update

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, setinterval

I have this method that uses `setInterval`

```
public getMoreMessages(route: string) {
  this.http.get(this.url + route + "?page=" + MessageService.plus)
           .subscribe(function(response) {
    if (response.json.length === 0) {
      MessageService.plus++;
      this.extractAndUpdateMessageList(response);
      return;
    };
  });
}
```

The problem here is that everything defined in `function` have to be `static` or else it will be `undefined`. This is why I declared `plus` as `static`, but I can't declare **extractAndUpdateMessageList(response: Response)** as `static` too.

Can someone please help me figure out how to write it correctly without having to declare my variables as `static`?

Thank you

Comment: where does it use `setInterval`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your context (`this`) inside the callback function of `subscribe` when you use `function() {}` syntax for callbacks. Use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to capture the correct `this`:

```
this.http.get(this.url + route + "?page=" + MessageService.plus)
  .subscribe((response) => { // Notice arrow function here
    if (response.json.length === 0) {
      MessageService.plus++;
      this.extractAndUpdateMessageList(response);
      return;
    };
  });
```

You don't have to make `MessageService.plus` as static as you will now get instance properties inside the callback with arrow functions.

Comment: This was actually what I tried first but I noticed it doesn't take in count the condition as if it's not there, whatever response.json is it does execute the code inside, i am really confused...

Comment: @jiji Sounds like an issue with your data. Check if `response.json` is an array and you logic is correct.

Comment: I switched to your technique `((response) => {`, and when I do `console.log(response.json())` within the brackets i always get `null`. But when I use `function(response) {` it prints correctly the array... I can't figure it out!!

Comment: If I do console.log(response.json().length) just before the if it print 3, it still executes the code within the if even if the condition is if if (response.json.length === 0) !!!

Comment: @jiji You know that is not possible. Have you changed your condition to `(response.json().length === 0)`?

Comment: Thank you so so much, this solved the problem as well as replacing `function(response) {` with `(response) => { `!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use

```
let that = this;
```

and use "that" in place inside the callback.

Comment: No, the whole point is to change the attribute of the class not just a local variable !!